# Would Averna, the Chaos Bloom allow you to get out all of your lands if you cascade and don't have a lower CMC spell in your deck?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If you fail to find a lower CMC spell in your deck while cascading, would [Averna, the Chaos Bloom](https://scryfall.com/card/cmr/589/averna-the-chaos-bloom) drop all of the land in your deck into play on one turn?

The wording on the card is:

> As you cascade, you may put a land card from among the exiled cards onto the battlefield tapped. (Do this after the last card is exiled but before deciding whether to cast a nonland card.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Cascade is defined as:

> **702.84a** Cascade is a triggered ability that functions only while the spell with cascade is on the stack. “Cascade” means “When you cast
> this spell, exile cards from the top of your library until you exile a
> nonland card whose converted mana cost is less than this spell’s
> converted mana cost. You may cast that card without paying its mana
> cost. Then put all cards exiled this way that weren’t cast on the
> bottom of your library in a random order.”

So if you don't have a lower CMC spell in your deck, you will exile your entire library one card at a time.  Once all cards are exiled, you get to put a land card onto the battlefield tapped.  Then you are done.